# No module named 'concurrent.futures'; 'concurrent' is not a package using Python 3.6.0

Tags: python-3.x, python-asyncio

when i do the following in python on the Mac OSX command line:

```
>>> from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor
```

i get

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'concurrent.futures'; 'concurrent' is not a package
```

`python --version` gives 3.6.0
using Virtualenvs, i have done `pip3 install asyncio` and also `pip3 install futures`.

Comment: `concurrent.futures` is [part of the standard library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html). How did you install Python?

Comment: downloaded from https://www.python.org/downloads/

Comment: running concurrent code results in the above error.

Comment: It sounds like something is wrong with your installation. Either that or you're shadowing `concurrent`. Do you have a `concurrent.py`?

Answer (score 39):

You probably have a file named `concurrent.py` in your project :-)

Comment: Thank you, udi, I came here searching for this issue and oversaw that I in fact do have concurrent.py in my path...

Comment: Magnificient :)!
I' ve just done same mistakes, too.